# How could I add a graph to a post at MSE?

Tags: support, images

How could I add a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) to a post at MSE ? Is it possible to do this with mathjax ? If not, what would be an other way to add graphs to an question/answer. To illustrate, I would like to add something like this:

[image]

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13841)

Comment: BTW if it is something for which many various pictures might already exist on the internet, it is worth trying Google Images. In this case, if you search for [Petersen graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=petersen+graph&tbm=isch) you will find several similar pictures.

Comment: See also [How can I draw a tree like this?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23055/how-can-i-draw-a-tree-like-this)

Answer (score 7):

Here's my workflow...

**Step 1**: create graph in LaTeX using [tikz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) to draw the graph, and the [standalone](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/standalone) document class.  (I use the [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) site if I get stuck.)  Here's an example.

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{2in}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,thick,circle,fill=blue!30,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]
  \tikzstyle{vertex2}=[draw,thick,circle,fill=green!30,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt]

  \draw[fill=red!15] (0,3) ellipse (0.25 and 2.4);
  \draw[fill=red!15] (2,3) ellipse (0.25 and 2.4);

  \draw (0,1) node[vertex] (v1) {};
  \draw (0,2) node[vertex] (v2) {};
  \draw (0,3) node[vertex] (v3) {};
  \draw (0,4) node[vertex] (v4) {};
  \draw (0,5) node[vertex] (v5) {};

  \draw (2,1) node[vertex2] (u1) {};
  \draw (2,2) node[vertex2] (u2) {};
  \draw (2,3) node[vertex2] (u3) {};
  \draw (2,4) node[vertex2] (u4) {};
  \draw (2,5) node[vertex2] (u5) {};

  \draw (v1) to[bend left] (v2);
  \draw (v1) to[bend left] (v3);
  \draw (v1) to[bend left] (v4);
  \draw (v1) to[bend left] (v5);
  \draw (v2) to[bend left] (v3);
  \draw (v2) to[bend left] (v4);
  \draw (v2) to[bend left] (v5);
  \draw (v3) to[bend left] (v4);
  \draw (v3) to[bend left] (v5);
  \draw (v4) to[bend left] (v5);
  \draw (u1) to[bend right] (u2);
  \draw (u1) to[bend right] (u3);
  \draw (u1) to[bend right] (u4);
  \draw (u1) to[bend right] (u5);
  \draw (u2) to[bend right] (u3);
  \draw (u2) to[bend right] (u4);
  \draw (u2) to[bend right] (u5);
  \draw (u3) to[bend right] (u4);
  \draw (u3) to[bend right] (u5);
  \draw (u4) to[bend right] (u5);

  \draw (u3) -- (v1);
  \draw (u3) -- (v2);
  \draw (u3) -- (v3);
  \draw (u3) -- (v4);
  \draw (u2) -- (v1);
  \draw (u2) -- (v2);
  \draw (u2) -- (v3);
  \draw (u2) -- (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

The `\resizebox{2in}{!}{ ... }` changes the size of the image; I adjust it via trial and error.

**Step 2**: Compile and convert to `.png` format.  I do this in [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/), where it takes just a click of a button.

**Step 3**: Upload the `.png` file.

[image: Graph]

---

*Note*: usually I don't bother writing most of the tikz code myself, but instead write a [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) script to write the tikz code for me.  I edit the output manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can add very basic graphs using mathjax:

```
\begin{array}{ccccc}
  &  & 1 &  \\
  &╱&   &╲  \\
5 &  &   & & 2 \\
| &  &   & & |  \\
4 &  & — & & 3 
\end{array}
```

\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & 1 & & 
\\ & ╱ & & ╲ \\
5 & & & & 2 & \\ | & & & & | \\
4 & & — & &3 
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

What you did seems to have worked. This is pretty much what everyone does: create an image using external software, and upload it to MSE via imgur.

Comment: I just got this from google images. Any external software that you would recommend ?

Comment: @Kasper I prefer SVG grahics for that (and in fact use a text editor more often than inkscape for simple graphs and graphics). Unfortunately, SVG is not supported for upload, so it needs to be converted (with gimp for example). I bet there are smarter options available, esp. with some math support.

Comment: @Kasper: personally, I use [Intaglio](http://www.purgatorydesign.com/Intaglio/), but it is Mac only. Check out [the link given by J.M.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13841) above. It seems to cover most of the programs I have seen others mention.

Comment: @kasper You might find some reasonable suggestions on TeX.SE, too. You can browse questions [tagged graphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs); for example you find there [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45734/drawing-graphs-in-latex). You can also have a look at the question about diagrams in [community polls](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls/1592#1592).