# How to make and paste an image of a graph in graph theory questions?

Tags: support, images

I saw references in meta to an app known as TikZ but I also found the statement that TiKz does not work yet. So I am left wondering how to generate images of graphs that I can paste into my questions.

Comment: Generate the images in TikZ in a TeX compiler, then upload the image here.

Comment: TikZ is a LaTeX package, not an "app".  If you are familiar with LaTeX, you can use the TikZ package to create graphs in a LaTeX document, then take a screenshot of that image (or otherwise export it to a reasonable image format), then upload that image here.  It is not a question of working "yet"---to the best of my knowledge, no one is planning on implementing TikZ here.

Comment: You can just draw the image in any app and take screenshot to upload with your question. Even hand drawn image on neat paper with sufficiently clear labeling of vertices and edges can be used. The idea is that the answerers get a clear idea of what is being asked.

Comment: Anna, have you tried [webgraphviz.com](http://www.webgraphviz.com)?

Comment: Some related posts on meta: [How could I add a graph to a post at MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9435) and [Is there a way to draw a graph (vertices & edges) in LaTeX on this website?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11049#11069) And on the main site: [Online tool for making graphs (vertices and edges)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13841), [What software is used to draw undirected graphs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31626), [Graph theory software?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58973) (Probably you can find several other related posts.)

Comment: Also related: [Using TikZ on math.stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9545). I will also mention this website mentioned among [Community Promotion Ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31296#31399): https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/

Comment: I'm not sure if the previous comments have covered this, so I will emphasize it.  Yes, mathJax is very similar to Latex.  And yes, in a latex document that is used to create a pdf by (for example) the **pdflatex** binary, images can be imbedded in the pdf by such Latex "*add-on's*" as PSTricks, Pgf-Tikz, or Asymptote.  **However,** to the best of my knowledge, this method of imbedding an image **does not analogize** to math-Jax.  Therefore, when needing to imbed an image into (for example) a math-Jax edited mathSE posting, the standard approach is as follows ...see next comment.

Comment: **Somehow**, create a graphics file on your hard disk (e.g. a *.jpg file, or some other graphics file format).  Then, when editing your mathSE query, use the "imbed graphics file" link to upload your graphics file to the mathSE site and simultaneously imbed the graphics file in your query.  There are various ways of creating a graphics file.  As suggested by my previous comment combined with other previous comments in this query, you can use (some sort of computer software) to generate a graphics image on your computer monitor and then take a screen capture. ...see next comment

Comment: I mention another option just to expand your intuition:  You can instead, simply write down details pertinent to your work on scratch paper and then use some sort of digital camera to create a graphics file (e.g. jpeg file).  Then simply transfer the jpeg file to your computer hard disk, and then proceed as in my previous comment.  I mention this option not because I recommend it, but merely to expand your intuition re the process of imbedding an image into a mathSE posting.